# Beginner Django: trouble defining URL paths

Tags: django, url

I have some experience with Python, but I'm very new to Django and web development in general.

I have an issue in which I have set up two URLs, but only one of them will ever be rendered: namely, the first one in the list of URL patterns. 
I'm just getting started, so basically, all I have right now is a page that displays a user registration form, and a basic "Hello, World" page.

Given the current configuration, and running the development server, whether I go to the URL `localhost:8000/mysite` or `localhost:8000/registration` I am taken to the registration form page. If I reverse the order of the two in the urlpatterns list in mysite/myapp/urls.py, both URLs take me to the "Hello, World" page.

I know I must be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

**mysite/myapp/urls.py** looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.registration, name='registration'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

My file **mysite/urls.py** looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin  
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^mysite/', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^registration/', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and **myapp/views.py** looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from myapp.forms import UserRegistrationForm

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the main page for MySite!")

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # stuff gets done with form            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/registration/')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'myapp/registration_form.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point putting patterns with different prefixes into the same included urlconf. That means there is no way to distinguish between them. Remember, all that's happening is that your browser is telling Django "serve me the content at this URL", so Django needs to have a distinct URL for each different view you want to serve.

If you want to serve both URLs without a prefix, then either include the whole urlconf without a prefix:

mysite/urls.py:

```
url(r'', include('myapp.urls'),
```

myapp.urls.py:

```
url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, name='registration'),
url('r^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

or, even simpler, don't bother with including an app-specific urlconf at all, and just use those two url patterns directly in mysite/urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access the registration page with the same url pattern (r'^$') that you have used for the index page.  So you should access registration page with smt different. For example

```
urlpatterns = patterns('registration',
    url(r'^registeration/$', views.registration),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Comment: This is the same as the below answer and doesn't work. With this solution, instead of both URLs calling the registration() function, both call the index() function.

Comment: are you sure you did edit the urls on your `mysite/urls.py`as recommended ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. I want to use localhost:8000/registration to access the registration page (registration() method in views), and localhost:8000/mysite to access the "Hello, World" page (index() method in views). None of the answers thus far have provided that solution.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you used for both is the same `r'^$'`, you must change the urls to something more general. That happens because the url routing gets the url identifies the text that match the regular expression and redirects to the first function it finds in the tuple.

I recommend the url for the `mysite/urls.py` for the home to be `r'^$'`, and the one for the registration to be `r'^registration/$'`

`urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, name='registration'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I make this change both paths now just take me to the mysite/ page (index() function)

Comment: I edited my answer, try to use the following configuration on the `mysite/urls.py` ,